# Abstract Base Class versus Service with Queue API

Tags: 8, queue

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure a custom module that uses the Queue API in D8.  I'm new to D8 and a bit rusty with OOP so forgive me if I'm breaking some recommended design pattern here...

I created a single custom module where multiple different queues need to process items differently, but each queue has common functionality that they may need to use between each other.  So my question is, should I create an abstract base class that extends `QueueWorkerBase`, make `processItem` abstract, and then add common functionality to the base class?

Something like this:

In src/Plugin/QueueWorker/ProcessQueueBase.php

```
abstract class ProcessQueueBase extends QueueWorkerBase {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  abstract public function processItem($data);

  protected function doSomethingCommon(){
    // Some common logic
  }
}
```

In src/Plugin/QueueWorker/ProcessQueueOne.php

```
class ProcessQueueOne extends ProcessQueueBase {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function processItem($data){
    // Do stuff now

    parent::doSomethingCommon();
  }    
}
```

In src/Plugin/QueueWorker/ProcessQueueTwo.php

```
class ProcessQueueTwo extends ProcessQueueBase {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function processItem($data){
    // Do stuff now

    parent::doSomethingCommon();
  }    
}
```

**OR** should I create separate classes that all extend `QueueWorkerBase` and then just create services for the common functionality.

Something like this:

In DoSomethingService.php:

```
class DoSomethingService {

  public function doSomethingCommon(){
    // Do something
  }

}
```

In src/Plugin/QueueWorker/ProcessQueueOne.php

```
class ProcessQueueOne extends QueueWorkerBase {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function processItem($data){
    // Do stuff

    $do_something = \Drupal::service('mymodule.doSomething');
    $do_something->doSomethingCommon();
  }    
}
```

In src/Plugin/QueueWorker/ProcessQueueTwo.php

```
class ProcessQueueTwo extends QueueWorkerBase {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function processItem($data){
    // Do stuff

    $do_something = \Drupal::service('mymodule.doSomething');
    $do_something ->doSomethingCommon();
  }    
}
```

Comment: This is a PHP question basically. But if you have classes that share a majority of the same functionality, you would fill in the methods in the abstract class and extend the class, then override (or add) methods you need to alter functionality for.

Comment: If you put the common method in a service then it runs in its own class instance which persists during the request. So this depends on whether the common method uses any states and whether they should persist in each plugin instance or in the shared service.

Comment: I'd prefer the latter, but with injecting dependencies. Although Traits are another possibility. If the it's common operations that don't depend on state then a trait could be pretty useful.

Comment: @mradcliffe My plan was to inject the dependencies, but for the sake of simplicity I chose not to write the full code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an abstract base class, but instead of creating another function `::doSomethingCommon`, partially implement `ProcessQueueBase::processItem` and call `parent::processItem` from the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context you provided I would suggest going for an Abstract class or a Trait.

I try to answer this questions when I doubt:

| Question | Abstract | Trait | Service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Does **doSomethingCommon()** relys on **QueueWorkerBase** methods or properties? | **Yes** | Yes | No |
| Is **doSomethingCommon()** a common functioanlity that may be used by any other class that does not extends from **QueueWorkerBase**, for example from a Controller or a Form? | No | **Yes** | Yes |
| Should I be able to call **doSomethingCommon()** individually from a function (or Drupal hook) or a global scope? | No | No | **Yes** |
| Should I be able to override or alter **doSomethingCommon()** functionallity in a class? | **Yes** | Yes | No |

Notice that some **Yes** are in highlighted. That is more of a personal preference on which I would use based on what will be easier to implement, maintain and understand from a quick look to the code.

I hope this helps you.